# "ich hätte früher dort gewesen sein müssen" zeit

Tags: grammar, tense

In dem Beispielsatz oben kommen vier Verben zum Einsatz. Hat diese Form einen eigenen Namen, oder ist das eine Kombination aus verschiedenen Formen (z. B. Perfekt und Konjunktiv II)?

Anderes Beispiel:

> Ich hätte das gewusst haben sollen.

Comment: Entschuldige mich, bitte! Als Deutschmuttersprachler stehe sogar ich doch manchmal auf einem Schlauch, wenn ich meinen Realschuelern, den Unterschied zwischen "Wenn ich gestern nicht frueh nach Hause gehen muesste....vs. "Wenn ich gestern nicht frueh haette nach Hause gehen muessen.." erklaeren muss!
:-)

Comment: @Sven D.: Ganz einfach: _Wenn ich gestern ... nach Hause gehen müsste_ ist so falsch wie _wenn ich gestern abreisen werde_. Das _müsste_ wird wie _eigentlich muss_ oder als hypothetisches _muss_ verstanden, also präsentisch, und das Präsens wird als Präsens oder als Futur verstanden, und das kann man nicht mit _gestern_ kombinieren.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich frage mich, ob man die Beispielsätze vor der grammatikalischen Untersuchung nicht vereinfachen könnte, ohne an Inhalt zu verlieren.

> Ich hätte früher dort sein müssen.

wäre eine „normale“ [irreale Modalverbkonstruktion](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Haupt-Konj2.html?MenuId=Word2123151#Anchor-Irreale-35882). „Hätte ... müssen“ ist das Modalverb (mit Hilfsverb *haben*), das im Plusquamperfekt Konjunktiv II steht; „sein“ das Hauptverb im Infinitiv. Genauso beim zweiten Beispiel:

> Ich hätte das wissen sollen/müssen.

Das vierte Verb („gewusst“, „gewesen“) ist jeweils das Hilfsverb zum Hauptverb, um jenes in die Vergangenheit zu setzen.

Die Änderung des Hauptverbs in eine Vergangenheitsform drückt in meinen Augen eine gewissen Abgeschlossenheit dieser Handlung aus (ich hätte dort sein müssen, wäre aber inzwischen wieder dort weggegangen; ich hätte es wissen müssen, es aber seitdem wieder vergessen können?). Sie kann also bedeutungstragend sein.

Ohne das es wirklich hundertprozentig passt, erinnert mich das aber eher an den umgangssprachlichen und nur selten angebrachten [„Plusquamperfekt II“ oder „Doppelplusquamperfekt“](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Komplex-Plusquam.html) (siehe auch [Wikipedia:Doppeltes Perfekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt) und der [Eintrag im Lexikon auf mediensprache.net](https://www.mediensprache.net/de/basix/lexikon/index.aspx?qu=Doppelplusquamperfekt)).

Die Konstruktion hat also zwar einen eigenen Namen, sie ist aber gleichzeitig auch aus verschiedenen Formen konstruiert (zweimal Verb plus Vergangenheits-Hilfsverb).

P.S. zum Thema „zu viele Verben“: „[Mögen hätt' ich schon wollen, aber dürfen hab ich mich nicht getraut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Valentin#Gefl.C3.BCgelte_Worte_Valentins)“ versammelt ihrer sechs :-)

Comment: Schönes Beispiel von Karl Valentin!

Comment: Statt "gewesen" hätte man aber auch einen Satz mit spezifischerem Verb gebildet haben können, etwa "Ich hätte protestiert haben sollen".

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann leider noch keine Kommentare schreiben, daher betrachte meine Antwort bitte als Ergänzung zu @tohuwabohus Antwort:

Der Sinn des vorliegendes Satzes

> Ich hätte das gewusst haben sollen.

ist der Ausdruck einer irrealen Begebenheit, die zeitlich zurückliegt und abgeschlossen ist. Er beinhaltet eine versäumte Verpflichtung, etwas vor einem zurückliegenden Zeitpunkt gewusst zu haben, im Gegensatz zur versäumten Verpflichtung, etwas an einem zurückliegenden Zeitpunkt zu wissen, was der folgende Satz ausdrückt:

> Ich hätte das wissen sollen.

So verstehe ich die beiden Aussagen als Muttersprachler, aber das heißt nicht, dass beide korrekt gebildet sind.

Der zweite Satz ist eine streng lehrbuchmäßige Konstruktion, bestehen aus

1. dem Konjunktiv II von "haben" in konjugierter Form,
2. dem Infinitiv Präsens des Vollverbs "wissen" und
3. dem Infinitiv Präsens des Modalverbs "sollen".

Ich habe keine Quelle gefunden, die die Konstruktion des ersten Beispielsatzes rechtfertigt. Allerdings muss ich @tohuwabohus Antwort um folgendes ergänzen, so dass vielleicht gemeinsam eine vollständige Lösung gefunden werden kann:

Die Form "gewusst haben" ist ein **Infinitiv Perfekt**. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es eine Regel gibt, die den Konjunktiv II Vergangenheit mit einem **Infinitiv Perfekt** statt des **Infinitiv Präsens** aus Schritt 2. bildet, um eine Vorzeitigkeit der Handlung gegenüber der [Betrachtzeit](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/446) des Satzes auszudrücken.

Answer (score 1):

Zunächst ist zu sagen, dass das *sollen* in "*ich hätte das gewusst haben sollen*" als Partizip Perfekt fungiert. Man spricht bei den Modalverben im Perfekt von einem "**Ersatzinfinitiv**", der für das Partizip 2 eintritt.

Man könnte fragen, ob die Vergangenheit dieses Ersatzinfinitivs *sollen* sich auf den Infinitiv *wissen* überträgt.

Dies scheint der Fall zu sein in einem Beispiel mit einem anderen Modalverb

> Ich wollte (da) einen Kaffee trinken, (aber dazu kam es da nicht mehr).

Das vergangene *wollen* bezieht sich hier auf ein nicht stattgefundenes vergangenes Kaffeetrinken in dieser Situation ("da") und ist nicht dadurch einzulösen, dass ich jetzt einen Kaffee trinke, und dem hätte auch nicht dadurch entsprochen werden können, dass ich irgendwann später doch noch einen Kaffee getrunken hätte.

Bei dem Satz

> ich hätte das wissen sollen

scheint der Fall analog zu liegen: Die vergangene Realität war, dass ich es (damals) nicht wusste oder dass mir (damals) einiges nicht klar war, obwohl ich mir rückblickend (jetzt) sage, dass man damals mit einigem Recht hätte erwarten können, dass ich es wüsste bzw. mir über weitere Konsequenzen im Klaren wäre. Das erwartbare Wissen liegt meiner Einschätzung nach in der Vergangenheit. Dass ich es jetzt weiß, heilt mein damaliges Unwissen nicht.

Der Vergangenheitsbezug des Wissens ergibt sich aus dem Vergangenheitsbezug des *hätte + Partizip Perfekt*. Es ist nicht erforderlich, die Vergangenheit dieses Wissens durch einen Infinitiv Perfekt ein weiteres Mal zu markieren.

Es sei denn, man hätte ein von tohuwabohu genanntes Doppelperfekt konstruieren wollen. Rein technisch wäre die so konstruierte Verbform dann als "*Konjunktiv II Doppelplusquamperfekt des Modalverbs 'sollen'*" zu bezeichnen. Ob man eine solche Konstruktion auch verstehen kann, wage ich nicht zu entscheiden, weil für mich Doppelperfekt- und Doppelplusquamperfektformen inhaltlich nicht gut zu greifen sind.

Grundsätzlich würde ich bezweifeln, dass überkonstruierte Verbalkomplexe überhaupt noch (gut) analysierbar sind. Zumindest erschweren sie das Verständnis. Dies betrifft u.a. Häufungen von Modalverben (*man sollte das verstehen können dürfen*) als z.B. auch passivische Futur-II-Konstrukte (*das hätte so nicht gesagt worden sein dürfen*). Derartiges wird normalerweise vermieden.

Man könnte übrigens auch fragen, ob der angestrebte Inhalt nicht auch mit

> ich hätte das haben wissen sollen

wiederzugeben wäre.

Answer (score 1):

"ich hätte früher dort gewesen sein müssen"

Es ist, wie gesagt, ein Konjunktiv II Vergangenheit mit Modalverb, das einzig Ungewöhnliche am Beispiel ist, dass der Infinitiv, mit dem das Modalverb kombiniert wird, ein Infinitiv Perfekt ist. Nun, der Infinitiv Perfekt drückt einfach Vorzeitigkeit aus.
Ein Modalverb im Präsens mit einem Infinitiv Perfekt ist relativ normal. Ein Modalverb im Perfekt oder Konjunktiv II / Vergangenheit wird selten in Kombination mit einem Infinitiv Perfekt gebildet, weil sich die Logik der Vorzeitigkeit meist nicht erschließt bzw. gar nicht gegeben ist. Auch im Beispielsatz ist ohne zusätzlichem Kontext die Logik der Vorzeitigkeit des Infinitivs nicht klar nachvollziehbar.